# Simple Chained HashMap

Tags: c++, beginner, hash-map

I am very inexperienced at C++.  I wrote a Hash Map which uses chaining for collision resolution.  I intentionally did not use smart-pointers, as the objective of this was to learn and showcase.  I have tested the code and removed all bugs I came across.  I am hoping to get feedback on bad practices and potential risks associated with my code.

**HashMap.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

#include "HashElement.h"

class HashMap
{
private:
    HashElement **map_;
    int size_;
    int count_;
public:
    HashMap(int);
    ~HashMap();
    int GetHash(int);
    void Put(int, std::string);
    std::string GetElement(int);
    bool Contains(int);
    void Remove(int);
    int GetCount();
};
```

**HashMap.cpp**

```
#include "HashMap.h"
#include "PrimeChecker.h"

HashMap::HashMap(int size)
{
    while (!PrimeChecker::IsPrime(size)){
        size++;
    }
    size_ = size;
    map_ = new HashElement*[size_]();
}

HashMap::~HashMap()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size_; i++){
        int hash = GetHash(i);
        if (!map_[hash]){
            continue;
        }
        HashElement *current_element = map_[hash];
        HashElement *next_element = map_[hash];
        while (next_element->next_element_){
            next_element = next_element->next_element_;
            delete current_element;
            current_element = next_element;
        }
        delete current_element;
    }
}

int HashMap::GetHash(int key){
    return key % size_;
}

void HashMap::Put(int key, std::string value){
    int hash = GetHash(key);
    if (!map_[hash]){
        map_[hash] = new HashElement(key, value);
    }
    else{
        HashElement *last_element = map_[hash];
        while (last_element->next_element_){
            last_element = last_element->next_element_;
        }
        last_element->next_element_ = new HashElement(key, value);
    }
    count_++;
}

std::string HashMap::GetElement(int key){
    int hash = GetHash(key);
    if (map_[hash]){
        HashElement *current_element = map_[hash];
        while (current_element->GetKey() != key && current_element->next_element_){
            current_element = current_element->next_element_;
        }
        return current_element->GetValue();
    }
    return nullptr;
}

bool HashMap::Contains(int key){
    int hash = GetHash(key);
    if (map_[hash]){
        HashElement *current_element = map_[hash];
        while (current_element->GetKey() != key && current_element->next_element_){
            current_element = current_element->next_element_;
        }
        if (current_element->GetKey() == key){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void HashMap::Remove(int key){
    if (!Contains(key)){
        return;
    }
    int hash = GetHash(key);
    HashElement *current_element = map_[hash];
    if (current_element->GetKey() == key){
        map_[hash] = currentElement->next_element_;
        delete current_element;
    }
    else{
        HashElement *previous_element = current_element;
        current_element = current_element->next_element_;
        while (current_element->GetKey() != key){
            previous_element = current_element;
            current_element = current_element->next_element_;
        }
        previous_element->next_element_ = current_element->next_element_;
        delete current_element;
    }
    count_--;
}

int HashMap::GetCount(){
    return count_;
}
```

**HashElement.h**

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class HashElement
{
private:
    int key_;
    std::string value_;
public:
    HashElement(int, std::string);
    ~HashElement();
    HashElement *next_element_;
    int GetKey();
    std::string GetValue();
};
```

**HashElement.cpp**

```
#include "HashElement.h"

HashElement::HashElement(int key, std::string value)
{
    key_ = key;
    value_ = value;
    next_element_ = nullptr;
}

HashElement::~HashElement()
{
}

int HashElement::GetKey(){
    return key_;
}

std::string HashElement::GetValue(){
    return value_;
}
```

**PrimeChecker.h**

```
#pragma once
namespace PrimeChecker
{
    bool IsPrime(int);
}
```

**PrimeChecker.cpp**

```
#include "PrimeChecker.h"

namespace PrimeChecker
{
    //This method was adapted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test
    bool IsPrime(int number)
    {
        if (number <= 3) {
            return number > 1;
        }
        else if (number % 2 == 0 || number % 3 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            for (unsigned short i = 5; i * i <= number; i += 6) {
                if (number % i == 0 || number % (i + 2) == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is quite good. Without touching on algorithmic and design aspects, I can see a few points that you can further improve with the current code:

- You are missing [Const Correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-correctness.html) on [const methods](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-member-fns). This is an important aspect of C++ that is not obvious, so it is common for beginners or people migrating from other languages to miss it.
- This is a bit of a personal suggestion, but I consider the **public** parts of a class to be more relevant for people reading my code, so I tend to place **public** methods and data first, followed by **protected** and finally **private** members, which are implementation details that only concern the programmer implementing the class(es).
- I suggest keeping function parameter names in your function prototypes, as this will add to the documentation of the code.
- For `HashMap`, I would change a few method names:

  Instead of `Put` to add a value to the map, I would call it `Insert`, to closer resemble the Standard [`map<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) data structure that most C++ programmers are familiar with.

  Also, instead of `GetElement` to fetch a value, I would name it `Find`, again to resemble the Standard map type but also because `Get*` implies a light weight operation while `GetElement` might be a linear search in the bucket chain if the value is not the first one.
- You need to give some thought to the [Rule of Three](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which is about how your class is going to behave regarding value copy/assignment. As it stands, one could create copies of a `HashMap` using `operator =` and the default copy constructor. That would be disastrous, since each instance of a map own its memory and a copy with `=` would be a shallow copy of just the pointer, leading to duplicate attempts to free the same memory.

  The simplest approach would be disabling copy and assignment by making `operator =` and the copy constructor private (or [deleting](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) them). A more robust solution is implementing custom ones that perform a deep copy of the map.
- `HashElement` doesn't seem to be used anywhere outside `HashMap`, so it could be an inner class declared inside the private section of `HashMap`.
- The destructor of `HashElement` is empty, so you should not declare one and let the compiler supply the default.
- Try to always initialize data in constructors using the constructor initialization list. Taking `HashElement` as example, the proper way would be:

  ```
    HashElement::HashElement(int key, std::string value)
        : key_(key)
        , value_(std::move(value))
        , next_element_(nullptr)
    { }
  ```

  Doing so will ensure that the members are also initialized by the constructor instead of the assignment operator.

  Also note [`std::move()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move) when initializing `value_`. This is part of the C++11 *move semantics*, which will remove a redundant copy that you don't need.
- Consider providing `operator []` to allow usage such as:

  ```
  myMap[42] = "hello world";
  ```

  The [Standard C++ map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) provides such operator. You might want to use it as a guideline:

  ```
  class HashMap {
      ...
      std::string& operator[] (int key);
  };

  std::string& HashMap::operator[] (int key)
  {
      // How you'll implement this depends.
      // If you follow the convention of std::map,
      // This method should create a new entry if the
      // <key, value> pair is not present, returning a 
      // reference to it one completed.
      // If the entry is already available, 
      // just return a reference to the value.
      //
      // Pseudocode:
      //  if (key !in map)
      //      insert(key, new string);
      //  return ref find(key); 
  }
  ```
- The namespace `PrimeChecker` seems a bit unnecessary and verbose. `IsPrime()` at the global namespace would be fine too.

Comment: Such a detailed analysis!  Thanks!  I am still going through everything and learning what it all means along the way.  But can you clarify on this one, please?:
"I suggest keeping function parameter names in your function prototypes, as this will add to the documentation of the code."

Comment: @Evorlor, sure. Take `Put(int, std::string)` for instance. It might not be clear which of the parameters is the *key* and which is the *value*. Not all maps necessarily use an integer as key (strings are also very common). If you instead keep the parameter names: `Put(int key, std::string value)` that becomes explicit. This is self-documenting. No need to write a commend at the top saying "first parameter is the key, second is the value".

Comment: I hate to ask, but I have a couple of follow up questions if you don't mind:  1. What redundant copy of value_ are you talking about? Why do I need to std::move() it, but nothing else?  2. Can you provide an example of operator[]?  I have read around and tried a few examples, but I keep getting a missing arguments error.

Comment: @Evorlor, If you notice it, the std::string parameter `value`, is being passed *by value* (C++ has pass-by-value, pointer and reference). When you pass a parameter by value, it is copied into the function. Move elides the copy by just, well, moving the local object to its final destination, as the name suggests. This is the recommended for modern C++11, that is,  passing by value using `std::move` when you are copying a parameter.

Comment: Move semantics are not easily explainable in this short comment section, so I recommend that you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413470/what-is-stdmove-and-when-should-it-be-used), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642357/c11-const-reference-vs-move-semantics) and [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html) links.

Comment: @Evorlor, I've added the signature and some comments for the `operator[]`. Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: strings are passed by value and ints are passed by reference? opposite of what i thought

Comment: @Evorlor, by default, everything is passed by value in C++, which involves a copy. For native types, that's what you want, but complex objects might be expensive to copy, so we should take extra care.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is a bug in `GetElement`. The hash of the key is just a modulo the size of the hashmap which means it's very easy to create different keys with the same hash. If you find an entry for a given hash value you just iterate the list until you either find the entry with the provided key or you have reached the end. If the end is reached the last entry in the list is returned even if the key didn't match. Bug reproduced [here](http://ideone.com/oz5WSy).
2. While putting the code through ideone it failed with a compile error in `Remove` due to `currentElement` not being declared - should have been `current_element` instead.
3. I think a lot of the operations could be simplified if you create a method which returns a pointer to the previous element of the one you are interested in (so that `prev->next` points to the entry you are interested in) or `nullptr` in case it's not found. This allows you to simplify implementations for finding and removing elements and reducing duplicate code.

Comment: 1. Great catch!  I removed " && current_element->next_element_".
2. Oops! Missed one when I was fixing my naming conventions.
3. Great idea! I will definitely work on making that method. I should have done that initially.